# Android Countdown timer, continue timer on new activity

Tags: java, android

I've created a countdowntimer that works but it starts again on each activity. I'm trying to save the countdown value and use it in the second activity. Below is the countdown code on my main activity page.

```
    //Countdown Start


    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {


        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        final int j = (int) millisUntilFinished / 1000;

        long timed;
        timed = millisUntilFinished;




            TextView textic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textic.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished));



            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
                public void run() {
                TextView textic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                textic.setText(Integer.toString((j)));;


                }
            });





            }


            public void onFinish() {        
            }
        }.start();

//Countdown Finish
```

I've tried storing the countdown value and then using passextra in my intent to pass "timed" but that didn't work. I've searched around and can't find any solution that works. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

================

EDIT

================

public class MainActivity extends startscreen{

```
private CountDownTimer timer3;
public void onCreate(){

    timer3 = new CountDownTimer(10000,100){

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            TextView displaytime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            displaytime.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished));}

         public void onFinish() {
         }

      }.start();




        };;

public void startTimer(){

}

public void cancelTimer(){

}
```

==============

## EDIT 2

```
            //Counter 1 
            Counter1 = new CountDownTimer(10000 , 1000) { 
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
                    mCounter1TextField.setText("Seconds left: " + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));


                } 


                public void onFinish() { 



                    mCounter1TextField.setText("Finished!"); 
                    // Counter1.start();
                } 
            }; 



              Counter1.start();


                    public void starttimer() {
       Counter1.start();


}
```

And then in my second activity i've got:

```
    MainActivity Counter1 = (MainActivity) getApplicationContext();
    Counter1.starttimer();

    TextView mCounter1TextField=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    mCounter1TextField.setText("Seconds left: " + (Counter1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Extend the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class and add your global timer there.  Your class would look something like this

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application{
    private CountDownTimer timer;
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        timer = new CountDownTimer(10000,100){
                .....
            };
    }
    public void startTimer(){
        ...
    }

    public void cancelTimer(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Start this timer by making a call to `getApplicationContext() from an activity`

```
MyApplication application = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
application.startTimer();
```

Also, make sure you rename your application in your Android manifest.

```
<application ... android:name=".MyApplication" .../>
```

Comment: How do I call this timer in my other activities? Thanks. I've posted the new code.

Comment: I've tried displaying the timer but each time I do it just stops responding on me. I've edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either writing the `CountDownTimer` in its own class and extend it as a `Service` and then start the service when you want to start the timer, or make it a Singleton so all activities access the same timer.

Comment: I attempted to create it in it's own class but the countdown wouldnt work, it just displayed a fixed value of 10. I'm still looking into how to create a singleton. I'm rather new to android. Thank you for the suggestion.